# why cannot i exit app after click on the close window

Tags: python, wxpython

the app is very simple, only having two windows: when i click on the **search** button, a new window will show out. but when i close the child and the parent window one by one, i found the app not exit at all(the IDLE told me that there was still something running)

```
#coding=utf8
import wx
SearchResult = ""
Name = ""
minPrice = 0
maxPrice = 0

class Output(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,-1,title,size = (300,600))
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        Result = wx.StaticText(panel2,-1,SearchResult,pos = (20,20),size=(260,560))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnAppClose)

    def OnAppClose(self, evt):
        msg = "Hold on there a minute"
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, msg, "Wait ...", 
            wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_YES:
            self.Destroy()
        else:
            return

        dlg.Destroy()

class TextCtrlFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,u'crawl',size = (600,300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        Label1 = wx.StaticText(panel,-1,u"name",pos = (30,20))
        self.inputText1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel,-1,"",pos = (90,20),size=(150,-1))
        self.inputText1.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        Label2 = wx.StaticText(panel,-1,u"price",pos = (270,20))
        self.inputText2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel,-1,"",pos = (330,20),size=(60,-1))
        Label3 = wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"----",pos = (400,20))
        self.inputText3 = wx.TextCtrl(panel,-1,"",pos = (430,20),size=(60,-1))
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, u"search",pos = (250,230))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnClick,self.button)
    def OnClick(self,event):
        Name = self.inputText1.GetValue()
        minPrice = self.inputText2.GetValue()
        maxPrice = self.inputText3.GetValue()
        SearchResult = Name + minPrice + maxPrice

        app2 = wx.App()
        frame2 = Output(self,u'result')
        frame2.Show()
        app2.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TextCtrlFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are starting two wx.Applications and mainLoops in your program. This is not needed.

Modify:

```
    app2 = wx.App()
    frame2 = Output(self,u'result')
    frame2.Show()
    app2.MainLoop()
```

with

```
    frame2 = Output(self,u'result')
    frame2.Show()
```

The *Living Dead* seems to be the MessageDialog that is working in its own loop.
You can fix this nasty problem in two ways:

1.- Do not hesitate and kill it mercilessly:

```
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_YES:
        dlg.Destroy()
        self.Destroy()
```

2.- Better, make it a child of the frame in order to be automatically and fully killed, without possibility of resuscitation in any creepy form, when the frame is closed (Note the `self`):

```
     dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, msg, "Wait ...", wx.YES_NO|wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)
```